# Efficient way to search specific string in multiple dataTable

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, datatable, dataset

From database I return a dataset containing one or more table.
those tables will have equivalent number of columns.

I want to check if any common row exists in multiple table with specific string of first table.

```
for(int i=0; i<ds.Table[0].Rows.Count;i++)
{
 var firstTableRowValue = ds.Table[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
 //Check  firstTableRowValue exists in other dataTables if exists retrive other column values and delete that row from the table.
}
```

what will be the fastest and effecient way to do in C#

Comment: You need to create a unionDataTable that will have all lthe tables except first table like this : http://forums.asp.net/t/1469565.aspx?How+to+combine+all+tables+in+a+data+set+into+one+table+Or+into+one+DataSet+ then perform a single search using linq.

Comment: I think my requirement is little different than his. I have to add two more column to be specifice in another table. I mean

i get my searched string in table[1] lets say
then
new table should have
SearchStringColumn |  Table0_Col1 | Table0_Col2 | Table1_Col1 | Table1_Col2

And Again if found in Table[2] then Add two more columns Table2_Col1 and Table2_Col2  and process goes on and on

Answer (score 0):

If data tables have identical structure it is efficient to use IEnumerable & Intersect or Except. This is really fast.